# Rewrite URL from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have three four pages

```
page.php?s=defaultpage
page.php?p=defaultpage
blog.php?post=defaultpage
projects.php?view=defaultpage
```

I have this exisiting URL redirect code snippet. The fourth page is new, and I would like to write a condition for that to only show projects/defaultpage

How do I achieve this with the existing Rewrite condition.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Renu/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?([a-z])=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  /blog\.php\?post=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/%1? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$ blog.php?post=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z])/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: When I rewrite I get Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line, before the last line:

```
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]+)/?$ project.php?view=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /?view=$1&$2=$3

in php with get is :

```
example.com/?view=profile&nick=NickName
```

with .htaccess

```
example.com/profile/NickName/
```